# Windows 10 error 740 with child processes, trying to adjust system time

Tags: windows-10, uac, runas, systemtime

So I got some child processes that need to be able to adjust System time on a windows 10 system. The way it has been done in the past iterations of Windows was simply forking children as Administrator so they would have permission to edit the system time.

**Things I have tried:**

- Opening up the permissions for changing system time through the Local Security Policy so that Admin privileges were no longer required.
- Making a custom task in tasksched.msc to run the child process as administrator.
- Passing `ruunas /user:Administrator app.exe` as the executing command to run the child process, the problem here is that prompting for the password is not an option every-time this process needs to run.
- Elevating the parent process is not an option sadly, though it does work.

I'm not sure what to try next.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a work around. I used the 2003 windows resource kit utility 'ntrights.exe' to open up the permissions on windows 10.
I ran ntrights.exe from the terminal and then the command:

`ntrights -U "UserAccountName" +R SeSystemtimePrivilege`

This allowed the process to set the time as necessary without needing administrator privilege.

Comment: note that the `"UserAccountName"` does include the quotation marks so you would put `"Teddd73"` if that was the username.

Answer (score 0):

There is now an open-source tool I wrote that is (I think) an improvement on the `ntrights` tool:

https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/PrivMan/

To grant `SeSystemtimePrivilege` ("change the system time") to the `user1` account, you would write:

```
PrivMan -a user1 -g SeSystemtimePrivilege
```

It also has options to revoke privileges/rights (`-r`), test whether an account has one or more privileges/rights (`t`), and to output a comma-delimited report containing all accounts and privileges assigned (`--csvreport`).